# Can I connect to Zookeeper server with a different version client?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I need to use zookeeper java client in my project A.

A has a dependency B which is a library that uses zookeeper 3.3.5 java client to connect to an "enterprise service directory" zookeeper cluster. This cluster is not under my control , I can't use it for my code.
A and B run in same classloader, code in A has to use 3.3.5 client.

There's another dependency C (it's Solr 4.2) which runs in a different JVM.
C use zookeeper 3.4.5 java client.

The problem is that A uses 3.3.5 client and C uses 3.4.5 client, but I don't want to build two different zookeeper clusters. Can they connect to same zk clusters? If they can, which version of server should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old client and newer server is a very common use case, esp. when upgrading - server moves to the next version while client stays on the old version for a period of time, slowly migrating (typically you have many more clients than servers). So this gets exercised a lot.

In particular 3.3 client/server are verified by the ZK community to work with 3.4 client/server so it should work just fine.

One thing that you do need to worry about is if you are using new features in a 3.4 client that are not in 3.3 and your server is 3.3. If you take advantage of e.g. multi, which was added in 3.4, then you would have trouble. Multi is not supported by 3.3 servers and would fail. If both clusters are 3.4 servers, or 3.3 server cluster and the clients are either 3.3 or 3.4 and not using features added after 3.3 then you should be fine.

Comment: I'm not using 3.4 client features, but I'm not sure if C is using them. So I will use 3.4 server. Thanks a lot :)